# Apply Web Part Connections to web parts on the ascx page of other web parts

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts, webpart-connection

I have created a visual web part that combines two other previously created web parts into one nicely styled web part. This is done simply by adding Register tags to the ascx page of the web part, and then adding the web part tags just as I would on a page layout, like so:

WebPart_ParentAssignmentsUserControl.ascx:

```
<%@ Register tagprefix="WebParts" namespace="Microsoft.SharePointLearningKit.WebParts" assembly="Microsoft.SharePointLearningKit, Version=1.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=24e5ae139825747e" %>
<%@ Register tagprefix="MyChildrenWebPart" namespace="MLG2010.WebParts.MyChildren.MyChildrenWebPart" assembly="MLG2010.WebParts.MyChildren, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9f4da00116c38ec5" %>

<WebParts:AssignmentListWebPart runat="server" ListScope="false" AllowEdit="True" AllowConnect="True" Title="Assignment List Web Part" IsIncluded="True" Dir="Default" SummaryWidth="150px" IsVisible="True" AllowMinimize="True" AllowHide="True" ExportControlledProperties="True" ZoneID="" ID="g_1c528b46_baf2_4cf2_a004_91f84c4f4556" FrameState="Normal" DisplaySummary="True" ExportMode="All" SuppressWebPartChrome="False" DetailLink="" HelpLink="" MissingAssembly="Cannot import this Web Part." PartImageSmall="" AllowRemove="True" ToolTip="Assignment List - Use this web part to keep track of your SharePoint Learning Kit assignments." HelpMode="Modeless" FrameType="Default" AllowZoneChange="True" PartOrder="0" Description="Display the assignments for an instructor or learner." PartImageLarge="" IsIncludedFilter="" __MarkupType="vsattributemarkup" __WebPartId="{1c528b46-baf2-4cf2-a004-91f84c4f4556}" WebPart="true" Height="" Width=""></WebParts:AssignmentListWebPart>
<MyChildrenWebPart:MyChildrenWebPart runat="server" PageSize="5" StudentsSiteURL="/student" PictureLibraryTitle="Students Picture Library" ADChildAttribute="otheripphone" Description="My WebPart" DefaultPictureURL="../../Students Picture Library/DefaultChild.jpg" ShowErrors="True" PictureLibraryUrl="../../Students Picture Library" Title="MyChildrenWebPart" ADEntryPoint="LDAP://dc=redconnect-test" __MarkupType="vsattributemarkup" __WebPartId="{d13a3729-e2b8-4436-ac1b-b75c914a3596}" WebPart="true" __designer:IsClosed="false" id="g_d13a3729_e2b8_4436_ac1b_b75c914a3596"></MyChildrenWebPart:MyChildrenWebPart>
```

The problem here, is that I need these two web parts to communicate via web part connections. since they are only added here on the aspx, sharepoint does not "know" about them, and thus they do not get a chrome and thus I cannot set up the web part connections in the browser.

Is there a way to set up web part connections on web parts that are added this way? Or maybe if I can just activate the chrome on these web parts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I separated the web part into the pieces that could connect normally, and then used styling to make it look as if they were one. I have not found any documentation on the consequences of putting web parts inside other web parts as i attempted.

Answer (score 1):

You can define the connection statically. Note that using this way, you cannot create/modify/delete the connection using the browser.

See:

[How to: Declare a Static Connection between Two Web Parts Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178188.aspx)

Comment: ive tried that but couldnt get it to work. it complained about not being able to find the web parts.

Comment: is it possible to do this on web parts inside other web parts, as mentioned in the question?